# EF model-binding with winforms and asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, entity-framework

I am in a project where there should be a web interface as well as a winforms interface. It will probably start with WinForms and in the future we will add an ASP.NET MVC web interface.

I have experience with ASP.NET MVC and EF6, but after reading how to bind EF POCO entities to winforms controls in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj682076.aspx , I realised that it needs to modify the entity definition (code first) exposing details for winforms implementantion.

Is there any way of hiding the dependencies of winforms from the model layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From definition and considering you're already using `MVC` and `MVVM`, you should remember that `POCO` are not designed to be bound to the view (ANY view at all). There are several posts around and even questions here on StackOverflow, just like these two: [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330535/why-its-not-a-good-idea-to-pass-entities-as-models-in-mvc) | [Second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345585/when-to-use-the-poco-objects-for-views-and-when-the-custom-viewmodel-classes) | (and many others).

Considering that statement, you should design a `ViewModel` that will map your `POCO` into useful items for your screen (either `HTML`, `Winforms`, native mobile or any other) and avoid using data annotations (keep them to a minimum ammount).

You may need two `ViewModel` libraries, one for `MVC` and another one for `Winforms`, each with it's very own configs and all, but since it's more about data transport and less about business logic, this is quite fine.

To wire `ViewModels` to `POCO` and vice-versa in a better (AKA: automatic) way, take a closer look into mapping libraries, like `AutoMapper` or some other. I like `AutoMapper` because with it I can build my mapping definition using code-first approach inside a diferent assembly, keeping everything really clean and avoiding data annotations (which I hate).

Comment: I will take the approach of putting the ```ObservableCollection``` in the WinForms ViewModel library and a plain-old list for MVC ViewModel library.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that in the scenario depicted, where the repository code is used by several different front-end projects, that there should be a common middle layer that abstracts the database from the UI.

Bind your winforms controls to the middle layer objects. It should have no knowledge of the data layer at all.

Comment: Do you refer to a layer of DTOs or ViewModels? So any service layer should return ViewModels instead of entity framework modelsl, isn't it?

Comment: UI should use ViewModels. Middle/Business/Service layer should deal in Models based on entities. At least that's what I've found leads to the least amount of confusion and maximum re-use.

Answer (score 0):

In a common case, it's not a problem to get a universal entity model. Indeed, to make navigations properties bindable in WinForms, MS recommends implementing the IListSource interface that automatically provides an IBindingList collection. However, you can use the ObservableCollection type for your navigation properties that are appropriate for web applications, and use the IBindingList in your WinForms application (if you are using the MVVM pattern, it's better to perform such conversion in the view model).